# How do I automatically disable internal wifi adapter when I plug in external USB wifi adapter, and auto-enable it when I unplug the USB adapter?

Tags: bash, scripts, wifi-hardware-switch

When I plug in the external USB wifi radio, I currently turn off the internal radio by manually executing:

```
sudo modprobe -r ath9k
```

Note:"ath9k" is the driver of the internal wifi adapter

When I unplug the external USB, then I turn the internal radio back on by manually executing:

```
sudo modprobe ath9k
```

It works perfectly as is, but I want to learn how to use the computer to do repetitive tasks like this.

I realize that the computer will work fine even with both radios operating, but I practice minimizing EMF exposure and pollution whenever feasible.

---

Thanks to help from @terrance, here is what I have created so far.  **The "add" rule works great! but the "remove" rule is not working yet.**

1. Created and tested a bash script that enables internal wifi device
2. Created and tested a bash script that disables internal wifi device
3. Put both bash script files into /usr/bin
4. Plug in external USB wifi device
5. Run: `ip link show`
6. Copy the MAC address of the device (ex. 00:c0:ca:b1:4a:84)
7. Create a text document with the following:

> ACTION=="add" \ , ATTRS{address}=="00:c0:ca:b1:4a:84" \ ,
> RUN+="/usr/bin/disableinternalwifi.sh"
>
> ACTION=="remove" \ , ATTRS{address}=="00:c0:ca:b1:4a:84" \ ,
> RUN+="/usr/bin/enableinternalwifi.sh"

8. Save the file as /etc/udev/rules.d/99-wifi.swapper.rules
9. `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger`
10. `sudo udevadm trigger`

**The "add" rule works, but the "remove" rule does not.**

---

I ran `udevadm monitor --subsystem-match=usb`, then I plugged in the external USB wifi device.  The sysfs path that displayed was: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0

Next I ran `udevadm test /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0`

Below are the relevant results from the test:

> Reading rules file: /etc/udev/rules.d/99-wifi.swapper.rules
>
> DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0
>
> DEVTYPE=usb_interface
>
> DRIVER=mt76x2u
>
> PRODUCT=e8d/7612/100
>
> TYPE=0/0/0
>
> INTERFACE=255/255/255
>
> MODALIAS=usb:v0E8Dp7612d0100dc00dsc00dp00icFFiscFFipFFin00
>
> ACTION=add
>
> SUBSYSTEM=usb
>
> ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=MediaTek Inc.
>
> ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4:1.0
>
> ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_4_1_0
>
> .MM_USBIFNUM=00
>
> USEC_INITIALIZED=4133499389
>
> run: 'kmod load usb:v0E8Dp7612d0100dc00dsc00dp00icFFiscFFipFFin00'
>
> Unload module index
>
> Unloaded link configuration context.

Comment: With setting up a udev rules you can run the commands to disable or re-enable your device based on if you insert or remove the USB device.  Possible solution:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71616/111521

Comment: @Terrance I followed your suggestion and made a udev rule.  At this point, it is not working.  Am I missing a basic step?

Comment: @terrance Please see my updates in the question that show my work with the udev rule.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Look at the next answer where it says to use the `ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}` instead.

Comment: @Terrance that did it.  The post https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-desktop-74/udev-not-doing-remove-rules-841733/ referred to in the post you suggested explains it in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked for me (much appreciation for assistance from @terrance):

1. Create a bash script that enables internal wifi device and save as usr/bin/enableinternalwifi.sh
2. Create a bash script that disables internal wifi device and save as usr/bin/disableinternalwifi.sh
3. Test both scripts for proper function
4. Insert external USB wifi device
5. `udevadm monitor --subsystem-match=usb --environment --udev`
6. Remove the USB device
7. Take note of a unique identifier generated by the udevadm monitor (example: PRODUCT=e8d/7612/100)
8. Create a text document with the following:

> ACTION=="add" \ , ENV{PRODUCT}=="e8d/7612/100" \ ,
> RUN+="/usr/bin/disableinternalwifi.sh"
>
> ACTION=="remove" \ , ENV{PRODUCT}=="e8d/7612/100" \ ,
> RUN+="/usr/bin/enableinternalwifi.sh"

9. Save the text file as /etc/udev/rules.d/99-wifi.swapper.rules
10. `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger`
11. `sudo udevadm trigger` (now it should work)

Comment: Very well written answer!  +1  :)